# SDL2 Window turns black on resize

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl-2

I have started to work with SDL2 and am not experienced with it. I am working on a Mac system. Almost everything has been good, but I have a problem that when a resizeable window is resized, while the handle is being dragged, the window turns black, and I can only repaint it after releasing. And I have checked that while the window is being resized, no event is being produced and I have no means to interfere or detect this, as the event loop is just paused. Is there any possible solutions?

Here is the code (Almost replica of a tutorial on handling resize event):

```
SDL_Event event;

SDL_Rect nativeSize;
SDL_Rect newWindowSize;

float scaleRatioW;//This is to change anything that might rely on something like mouse coords
float scaleRatioH; //(such as a button on screen) over to the new coordinate system scaling would create

SDL_Window * window; //Our beautiful window
SDL_Renderer * renderer; //The renderer for our window
SDL_Texture * backBuffer; //The back buffer that we will be rendering everything to before scaling up

SDL_Texture * ballImage; //A nice picture to demonstrate the scaling;

bool resize;

void InitValues(); //Initialize all the variables needed
void InitSDL();     //Initialize the window, renderer, backBuffer, and image;
bool HandleEvents(); //Handle the window changed size event
void Render();            //Switches the render target back to the window and renders the back buffer, then switches back.
void Resize();      //The important part for stretching. Changes the viewPort, changes the scale ratios

void InitValues()
{
    nativeSize.x = 0;
    nativeSize.y = 0;
    nativeSize.w = 256;
    nativeSize.h = 224; //A GameBoy size window width and height

    scaleRatioW = 1.0f;
    scaleRatioH = 1.0f;

    newWindowSize.x = 0;
    newWindowSize.y = 0;
    newWindowSize.w = nativeSize.w;
    newWindowSize.h = nativeSize.h;

    window = NULL;
    renderer = NULL;
    backBuffer = NULL;
    ballImage = NULL;

    resize = false;
}

void InitSDL()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        //cout << "Failed to initialize SDL" << endl;
        printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);
    }

    //Set the scaling quality to nearest-pixel
    if(SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "0") < 0)
    {
        //cout << "Failed to set Render Scale Quality" << endl;
         printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);
    }

    //Window needs to be resizable
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Rescaling Windows!",
                                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                                    256,
                                                    224,
                                                    SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    //You must use the SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE flag in order to target the backbuffer
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,
                                                      -1,
                                                      SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED |
                                                      SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);

    //Set to blue so it's noticeable if it doesn't do right.
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 200, 255);

    //Similarly, you must use SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET when you create the texture
    backBuffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
                                                       SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat(window),
                                                       SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET,
                                                       nativeSize.w,
                                                       nativeSize.h);

    //IMPORTANT Set the back buffer as the target
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, backBuffer);

    //Load an image yay
    SDL_Surface * image = SDL_LoadBMP("Ball.bmp");

    ballImage = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
}

bool HandleEvents()
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
    {
       printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);
       if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
       {
             printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);
            return true;
       }
        else if(event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT)
        {
            if(event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED)
            {
                resize = true;
                printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

void Render()
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, ballImage, NULL, NULL); //Render the entire ballImage to the backBuffer at (0, 0)
    printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL); //Set the target back to the window

    if(resize)
    {
        Resize();
        resize = false;
    }
    printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, backBuffer, &nativeSize, &newWindowSize); //Render the backBuffer onto the screen at (0,0)
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer); //Clear the window buffer

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, backBuffer); //Set the target back to the back buffer
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer); //Clear the back buffer
    printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);

}

void Resize()
{
    int w, h;
    printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);

    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);

    scaleRatioW = w / nativeSize.w;
    scaleRatioH = h / nativeSize.h;  //The ratio from the native size to the new size

    newWindowSize.w = w;
    newWindowSize.h = h;

    //In order to do a resize, you must destroy the back buffer. Try without it, it doesn't work
    SDL_DestroyTexture(backBuffer);
    backBuffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
                                   SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat(window),
                                   SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, //Again, must be created using this
                                   nativeSize.w,
                                   nativeSize.h);

    SDL_Rect viewPort;
    SDL_RenderGetViewport(renderer, &viewPort);

    if(viewPort.w != newWindowSize.w || viewPort.h != newWindowSize.h)
    {
        //VERY IMPORTANT - Change the viewport over to the new size. It doesn't do this for you.
        SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, &newWindowSize);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    InitValues();
    InitSDL();

    bool quit = false;
    printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);

    while(!quit)
    {
        printf("%d\r\n", __LINE__);
        quit = HandleEvents();
        Render();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm [pretty sure](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute) you're supposed to call `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` *before* you create the window.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I don't think that's related to the problem. That's remaining code of some test. But I'll test it again.

Comment: Yup, moving it to before creating the window didn't change the situation. But thanks for inspecting the code thoroughly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, after fighting a bit with SDL2, I got it working with macOS 10.12.

Here is the problem:

1. SDL2 catches resize events and resends only the last 3 when you poll events using `SDL_PollEvent(&event)` for example.
2. During this time (you pressed left mouse click on resize area and hold the mouse) the `SDL_PollEvent` is blocking.

Here is the workaround:

Luckily, you can hook into the event handler using `SDL_SetEventFilter`. This will fire every time a event is being received. So for all resize events as they occur.

So what you can do is to register your own event filter callback that basically allows every event (by returning `1`), listens on resize events, and sends them to  your draw loop.

Example:

```
//register this somewhere
int filterEvent(void *userdata, SDL_Event * event) {
    if (event->type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event->window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED) {
        //convert userdata pointer to yours and trigger your own draw function
        //this is called very often now
        //IMPORTANT: Might be called from a different thread, see SDL_SetEventFilter docs
        ((MyApplicationClass *)userdata)->myDrawFunction(); 

        //return 0 if you don't want to handle this event twice
        return 0;
    }

    //important to allow all events, or your SDL_PollEvent doesn't get any event
    return 1;
}


///after SDL_Init
SDL_SetEventFilter(filterEvent, this) //this is instance of MyApplicationClass for example
```

Important: Do not call `SDL_PollEvent` within your `filterEvent` callback, as this will result in weird behaviour of stuck events. (resize will not stop sometimes for example)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This does work on Windows.  But on Windows, it the filter seems to be always run on the main thread.

Comment: I can't find any guarantee anywhere that promises that SDL_PollEvent() won't return while the code in `filterEvent` is running.  Not having that synchronization guarantee means we will need to use mutexes (assuming `myDrawFunction` can't handle being called from two threads simultaneuously).

Comment: This answer works, but I don't think it's technically correct. Resizing sends several `SDL_WINDOWEVENTS`, the last of which will be `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`. If we read the SDL source for that event, sure enough it says "Window has been exposed and should be redrawn". The fact that you added a call to `myDrawFunction();` also just happens to work because `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` is also one of the events sent before `EXPOSED`.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that this is not specific to my code, and it is a part of a wider problem with all the OpenGL libraries in MacOSX. Although recent patches in GLFW has fixed it, and in the GLUT version which is provided with XCode itself, it is quite better and you just observe a flicker in the window while resizing.

https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/2800
https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/2456

The problem is because of the blocking nature of the OSX window manager, which blocks all the events until the mouse is released.

To solve this, you should manipulate the library you are using and recompile it. You should add these or something similar (depending on your development environment) to the resize handler to bypass the block:

```
ofNotifyUpdate();
instance->display();
```

which is disastrous, if you are a novice, and want the ability to use library updates without much difficulty. Another solution is to override the SDL behaviour, by writing another event handler that does that. It is better as it doesn't need editing the SDL code, but adds a pile of platform specific code that I personally don't tend to and would cause a lot of problems that I don't want to spend time fixing.

After 2 days of searching, because I had just started the project and not implemented much relying on SDL, I decided to switch to GLFW which has the smoothest resize handling and I observe no flicker.

Comment: What do you mean with "resize handler"? It's not very clear where those two lines of code should be placed. `SDL_PollEvent` is only sending one event when resize is done, so you can't hook into it in user-space.